# Regex with If in VBScript to find and write results

Tags: regex, vbscript

I have a VBScript that is working but I would like to improve the efficiency of it through regex, for example, in an environment I look for several versions of SQL Server through of RTM:

```
10.5.1720.0 SQL Server 2008 R2 CU2
10.5.1702.0 SQL Server 2008 R2 CU1
9.00.4305   SQL Server 2005 SP3 CU10
9.00.4294   SQL Server 2005 SP3 CU9
8.00.2039   SQL Server 2000 SP4 
8.00.760    SQL Server 2000 SP3
```

I would like the script to recognize if the string is "^10.*" Then it should write SQL Server 2008 if not "^9.*" Write SQL Server 2005 and so on

So here's my script:

```
Dim mts, objShell, PV
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set ArgObj = WScript.Arguments
PV = "$(PV)"
Set regEx = New RegExp
regEx.IgnoreCase = True
regEx.Global = True
regEx.MultiLine = True
regEx.Pattern = "^10\.*"

If PV = "7.0.623" Then
    WScript.Echo "7.0"
ElseIf PV = "7.0.699" Then
    WScript.Echo "7.0"
ElseIf PV = "7.0.842" Then
    WScript.Echo "7.0"
ElseIf PV = "7.0.961" Then
    WScript.Echo "7.0"
ElseIf PV = "7.0.1063" Then
    WScript.Echo "7.0"
ElseIf PV = "8.0.194" Then
    WScript.Echo "2000"
ElseIf PV = "8.0.384" Then
    WScript.Echo "2000"
ElseIf PV = "8.0.532" Then
    WScript.Echo "2000"
ElseIf PV = "8.0.760" Then
    WScript.Echo "2000"
ElseIf PV = "8.0.2039" Then
    WScript.Echo "2000"
ElseIf PV = "13.1.4001.0" Then
    WScript.Echo "2016"
Else
    WScript.Echo "DTP"
End If
```

Is there any way I can reduce through Regex in VB?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend combining a regular expression with a [`Select Case`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ef9w614) statement.

```
Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "^(\d+)\."

For Each m In re.Execute(PV)
    Select Case m.Submatches(0)
        Case "7"  : version = "7.0"
        Case "8"  : version = "2000"
        Case "9"  : version = "2005"
        Case "10" : version = "2008"
        Case "13" : version = "2016"
        Case Else : version = "DTP"
    End Select
Next

WScript.Echo version
```

Answer (score 0):

Different approach: Using `Split` to get the leading number and a dictionary (data) instead of `Case` (code):

```
Option Explicit

Function makeDict(sK, sV)
  Dim d : Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  Dim aK : aK = Split(sK)
  Dim aV : aV = Split(sV)
  Dim i 
  For i = 0 To UBound(aK)
      d(aK(i)) = aV(i)
  Next
  d(Null) = aV(i)
  Set makeDict = d
End Function


Dim d : Set d = makeDict("10 7", "2008 7.0 DTP")

Dim ts : Set ts = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile("data.txt")
Do Until ts.AtEndOfStream
   Dim s : s = ts.ReadLine()
   Dim k : k = Split(s, ".")(0)
   Dim r
   If d.Exists(k) Then
      r = d(k)
   Else
      r = d(Null)
   End If
   WScript.Echo s, "=>", r
Loop
ts.Close
```

output:

```
cscript 46691612-2.vbs
10.5.1720.0 SQL Server 2008 R2 CU2 => 2008
10.5.1702.0 SQL Server 2008 R2 CU1 => 2008
9.00.4305 SQL Server 2005 SP3 CU10 => DTP
9.00.4294 SQL Server 2005 SP3 CU9 => DTP
8.00.2039 SQL Server 2000 SP4 => DTP
8.00.760 SQL Server 2000 SP3 => DTP
7.00.760 SQL Server sieben => 7.0
```

Answer (score 0):

My friend helped me and made this script that worked well:

```
Dim mts, objShell, Version
set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set ArgObj = WScript.Arguments
Version ="$(Version)"
erro="DTP"
a=Split(Version,".")
IF uBound(a) > 0 Then
    VersionInt = CInt(a(0))
    saida=""
    IF VersionInt = 7 or VersionInt = 6 Then
        saida = VersionInt
    End If
    IF VersionInt = 8  Then
        saida = "2000"
    End If
    IF VersionInt = 9  Then
        saida = "2005"
    End If
    IF VersionInt = 10  Then
        saida = "2008"
        IF uBound(a) > 1 Then
            ReleaseVersionInt = CInt(a(1))
            If ReleaseVersionInt > 49 then
                saida = "2008 R2"
            End If
        End If
    End If
    IF VersionInt = 11  Then
        saida = "2012"
    End If
    IF VersionInt = 12  Then
        saida = "2014"
    End If
    IF VersionInt = 13  Then
        saida = "2016"
    End If
    IF VersionInt = 14  Then
        saida = "2017"
    End If
    If saida="" Then
        Wscript.echo erro
    else
        Wscript.echo saida
    End IF
Else
    Wscript.echo erro
End IF
```